# preventing ssh command from opening xquartz on every session

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh, xquartz

Whenever I use ssh, after I type the password, xQuartz pop ups in the dock and terminal window looses focus. This happens even if there's no an X session. Why? How to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Just to clarify - forwarding the X ports over requires using the -X switch within ssh. You want to use the switch in order to use xQuartz within the ssh session, yet retain the focus on the terminal window until you actually do so?

Comment: I just want a normal command line access, not x window session. I didn't use -X. For example: `ssh user@server.local`

Comment: Odd. Is there any alias or anything that may be mapped to your ssh command?

Comment: I don't think. There is nothing that I added to ssh in .profile or .bashrc.

Comment: Do you have anything in your ~/.ssh/config file that may trigger the use of X11? eg, the `ForwardX11` option would do it.

Comment: @mjturner I don't have a config file in that folder. There are just a few RSA keys and the known hosts.

Comment: I think i found the config in `etc/ssh_config`, the last uncommented lines are: `ForwardX11 yes
Host *
XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved by myself. XQuartz installation added a custom configuration for ssh in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (or `/etc/ssh_config` for older macOS versions). I have just removed `ForwardX11 yes` and ssh won't open XQuartz anymore.

Below shows the file contents that's causing XQuartz to open.

```
$ tail -5 /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    SendEnv LANG LC_*

# XAuthLocation added by XQuartz (https://www.xquartz.org)
Host *
    XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

Comment: The config may also be in `~/.ssh/config` as in my case. I forgot that I set it on a per-host config. It looked like this (except comments can't have multiline code blocks?):

    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    XAuthLocation <blah>

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to by mjturner in the comments, the actual answer to this is to ensure the following is in your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
ForwardX11 no
```

If set to `yes`, XQuartz will simply re-add its settings to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Comment: This reads as if if the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file gets updated. Is this really the case?

Comment: Yes, if you comment out the lines in the accepted answer in MACOS 10.11, they will be reinstated if ForwardX11 is yes