# Preventing ssh command from opening xquartz on every login

Tags: dock, ssh, catalina, x11, xquartz

Whenever I use ssh, after I type the password, xQuartz pop ups in the dock. It is a similar question to [preventing ssh command from opening xquartz on every session](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91644/preventing-ssh-command-from-opening-xquartz-on-every-session), but in my case, I want X forwarding, so I have set `ForwardX11` to `yes` in the config file but now I do not want opening XQuartz in dock every time I log into a machine via ssh command. What should I do? I have already tried to change also `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (where everything was anyway commented out).

I am using Catalina.

Comment: Hmm...this is strange, because in ```etc/ssh/ssh_config``` there is also a head text with explanations which I thought is commented out by # sign. And there are lines in the bottom
```Host *
       SendEnv LANG LC_*

# XAuthLocation added by XQuartz (http://www.xquartz.org)
Host *
        XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth```
which doesn't follow # sign.

I tried anyway to change ForwardX11 to yes there but the xQuartz is still opening.